# Specify proper route to call a WebApi 2 Controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I created an PublicController.cs that will returns list of agents. I then build and run the project and open Postman change the mode to get and call http://localhost:50159/api/public/Agents the message I get back is

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:50159/api/public/Agents'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Public' that matches the request."
}
```

Is there something I am missing?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Agents(string key, string diseaseId)
    {
        GuardKey(key);

        var result = AgentsDataService.GetAgents();



        return Json(result);
    }
```

Comment: try adding a route to your action attribute - [HttpGet("agents")] - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#route-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, WebApi 2 controllers' names are registered by convention i.e. `PublicController` gives us `/api/Public` during runtime.

you try to access `api/public/Agents`, however your controller may lie at `api/Public`.
You need to specify a **Route** in `RouteConfig.cs` or apply a Route as an attribute for a method.

There is a good Microsoft [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) that describes routes more precisely.

Comment: I checked RouteConfig.cs and it has API/controller/action for the routes routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}");

Comment: Indeed `outes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}");` will process route-attributes you specify just before your method in controller.
You need to specify a custom one - the one that suits your needs.